# how to calculate date occurances between 2 dates

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following 2 datasets

```
Dataset-1---------------------
ID        Date_1      
 A      2020-08-21       
 A      2020-08-10
 B      2020-09-11
 B      2020-08-22

Dataset-2--------------------------
ID       date_2
A        2020-07-31
A        2020-07-31
A        2020-07-30
A        2020-08-02
B        2020-08-31
B        2020-09-12
B        2020-09-10
```

I need a 1st dataset, like the following:-

```
ID        Date_1      no_occurance_in_last_30_days
 A      2020-08-21        4
 A      2020-08-10        4
 B      2020-09-11        2
 B      2020-08-22        0
```

For every customer , have another column 'no_contact_in_last_30_days' in dataset 1 & have the number of occurances of that customer from dataset 2 which is in the last 30 days of Date_1 in dataset 1.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with lambda function and filtering matching `ID` by [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and checking dates of `date_2` [`.between()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) `Date_1` and 30 days before `Date_1` (calculated by `- pd.offsets.Day(30)`) and take the count of such entries with [`.sum()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.sum.html), as follows:

```
# convert dates from string to datetime format if necessary
df1['Date_1'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date_1'])
df2['date_2'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['date_2'])

df1['no_occurance_in_last_30_days'] = (df1.apply(lambda x: 
                                           df2.loc[df2['ID'] == x['ID']]['date_2']
                                              .between(x['Date_1'] - pd.offsets.Day(30), x['Date_1'])
                                           .sum(),
                                       axis=1)
                                   )

print(df1)

  ID     Date_1  no_occurance_in_last_30_days
0  A 2020-08-21                             4
1  A 2020-08-10                             4
2  B 2020-09-11                             2
3  B 2020-08-22                             0
```

Comment: Getting error as     
AttributeError: 'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'between'

Comment: @sayan_sen That's weird.  I tested it in my machine.  What's the Pandas version you are using ?

Comment: version pandas (1.1.5)

Comment: @sayan_sen  See my edit adding codes to replace `.between()` by `ge` and `le`.  Please try and let me know whether you can use it.

Comment: error --
AttributeError: 'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'ge'       the Dtype of date_1 & date_2 are datetime64[ns]

Comment: resolved ge & le error  by replacing '_ ge _' and ' _ le _,' however the new error is AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'sum'

Comment: @sayan_sen  Let me take a further look.  I got some clue.  Will come back to you soon!

Comment: @sayan_sen  I have simulated the error case and fixed the problem.  See the edited codes above.  In effect, I changed the code fragment from `df2.set_index('ID').loc[x['ID']]` to `df2.loc[df2['ID'] == x['ID']]` in the original codes.  And we can now keep on using the more convenient `.between()`.   Apologize for the inconveniences caused.

Comment: The problem happens when there is `ID` in df2 with only one row.  This situation was not discovered when I performed testing based on your sample data which has every ID with 2 rows or more.